# Render an image from base64 in golang

Tags: http, go

I would like to render an image from base64 in golang (here the twitter icon)

```
package main

import (
    base64 "encoding/base64"
    "fmt"
    "io"
    "net/http"
    "strconv"
)

func pix(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    fmt.Fprintf(w, "Hi there, I love %s!", r.URL.Path[1:])
    var cookie *http.Cookie
    cookie, err := r.Cookie("csrftoken")
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("error")
        fmt.Println(err)
    }
    fmt.Printf(cookie.Value)
    w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "image/jpeg")
    p, err := base64.StdEncoding.DecodeString("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")
    if err != nil {
        http.Error(w, "internal error", 500)
        return
    }
    w.Header().Set("Content-Length", strconv.Itoa(len(p))) //len(dec)
    io.WriteString(w, string(p))
}

func main() {
    http.HandleFunc("/pix/", pix)
    err := http.ListenAndServe(":9080", nil)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }
}
```

But it doesn't display anything and when I try to go to the URL; it downloads a file that contains error. Anyone have any idea why this is?

Comment: This is not the issue, but you should replace `io.WriteString(w,string(p))` with the more efficient and simpler `w.Write(p)`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are writing data to client other than the image. Specifically, this line:

```
fmt.Fprintf(w, "Hi there, I love %s!", r.URL.Path[1:])
```

You browser tries to render the content as a JPEG, but fails because of this extra data, so it prompts you to download it instead. Remove it and the picture will be displayed correctly.

You should also follow @Mellow Marmot's suggestion and use `w.Write(p)` instead of `io.WriteString(w, string(p))`.